# AngularJS : $sce.trustAsResourceUrl is not working in iframe

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, encoding, angular-ui-router

I am trying to open url inside my app through iframe. But $sce.trustAsResourceUrl is not working as expected.

```
var userDetails = {'userId' : $scope.userId, 'userName':$scope.userName,'userCountry':$scope.userCountry}
var iframeUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://......?userDetails='+userDetails);
```

When i debug the iframeUrl , i am getting the value of iframeUrl as

```
   Object( $$unwrapTrustedVAlue= function 

   _proto_ : {unsupported : no to String() function in type object]
```

In the receiving end, the userDetails is not getting passed and it is just passed as (object %20 object). How do i fix this issue and pass the proper value of userDetails object?

Comment: You can't concatenate a string and an object. What are expected results of the url?

Comment: i want the url string with params

Comment: That isn't an example. Not clear what format should be